# Difference between "view.window().run_command" and "view.run_command"

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

What is the practical difference between `view.window().run_command(...)` and `view.run_command(...)`?

Here are two versions of the same plugin, with two minor changes:

(It will convert tabs to spaces on save. You need `"expand_tabs_on_save": true` in preferences).

One:

```
# https://coderwall.com/p/zvyg7a/convert-tabs-to-spaces-on-file-save
import sublime, sublime_plugin, os

class ExpandTabsOnSave(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
  def on_pre_save(self, view):
    if view.settings().get('expand_tabs_on_save') == 1:
      view.window().run_command('expand_tabs')
```

Two:

```
# https://github.com/bubenkoff/ExpandTabsOnSave-SublimeText
import sublime_plugin # <---------- `sublime` and `os` removed

class ExpandTabsOnSave(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
  def on_pre_save(self, view):
    if view.settings().get('expand_tabs_on_save') == 1:
      view.run_command('expand_tabs') # <--------- `window()` removed
```

What have changed in it's behaviour with these changes?

Comment: Just for the record: As I discovered today the code posted at Coderwall [is just an old version of GitHub's code](https://github.com/bubenkoff/ExpandTabsOnSave-SublimeText/commits/master/ExpandTabsOnSave.py).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Sublime Text, commands can be defined to operate at an `Application` level ([`ApplicationCommand`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.ApplicationCommand)), a `Window` level ([`WindowCommand`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.WindowCommand)), or a `View` level ([`TextCommand`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.TextCommand)).

Typically only `TextCommand`s modify the buffer, or settings which only affect the current buffer, `WindowCommand`s the current window layout or other related settings, and `ApplicationCommand`s global preferences etc.

In my experience, executing a `WindowCommand` on a `View` object does nothing. Example:

```
view.run_command('set_layout', {"cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1]], "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0], "rows": [0.0, 1.0]})
```

[But executing a `TextCommand` on a `Window` object implicitly targets that window's currently active view.](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/commands.html#command-dispatching) When executed from the ST console, it will affect the ST console's input text area.

```
window.run_command('insert', { 'characters': 'testing123' })
```

So, the answer is that there could be a difference depending on the type of command, and whether the `View` you want to execute the command on is the active one or not.

---

In terms of the `import`s removed, there is no effect as those imports were not used in the plugin.

Comment: Excellent explanatio, but I still don't understand some things. Both versions of plugin works fine. However, when I manually launch `view.window().run_command('expand_tabs')` in console - it doesn't work. `view.run_command('expand_tabs')` works fine. Why?

Comment: because in the console, `view` refers to the main view, (as does `view.window().active_view()`), but when it forwards the command from the window to the view with input focus, it delegates to to the console's input text area, and the effect of expanding tabs on an empty input box is... nothing.